# How to create Cognos Report Without using Framework Manager??

Tags: cognos-bi

I am having one table tbl_Case_Validation and in that 4 column are there.
Now I want to make simple Cognos List report but without using Framework Manger, mean run List report directly throug SQL query.
Is it possible creating Reports without FM ??
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, at least not with 8.4. I haven't used Cognos 10 yet so that may be different.

The model created by Framework manager is a vital layer for translating the data view into a business view and is required even when it's a one-to-one mapping between the two.

However, the creation of such a one-to-one model is fairly painless so I'm not sure what the reticence is.

Answer (score 1):

Cognos 8 and newer is fundamentally built around the concept of the model. Each report needs to be based off a single model.

However, if you already had a model against this data source, you could insert Custom SQL from within Report Studio and do a Select * against the table which isnt modeled.

I would caution against this, even for a POC, but it's technically possible.